# String intern method logic

Tags: java, string

**Scenario 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s1 = "Testing";
        String s2 = new String("Testing");
        s2.intern();
        if(s1==s2){
            System.out.println("s1 equals to s2");
        }else{
            System.out.println("s1 is not equal to s2");
        }

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**    `s1 is not equal to s2`.

**Scenario 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        String s1 = "Testing";
        String s2 = new String("Testing").intern();
        if(s1==s2){
            System.out.println("s1 equals to s2");
        }else{
            System.out.println("s1 is not equal to s2");
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**  `s1 equals to s2` .

My question is what is the difference between `new String("Testing")` and `new String("Testing").intern()` ?

Comment: Not a duplicate @TimBiegeleisen.  This is to do with assigning a value to a variable, not to do with string comparison.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry...closed too quickly :-)

Comment: Found a better one :-)

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for [`String.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()):

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.

Your code discards the return value, so there's no reason to expect any effect.

Comment: As an addendum, sometimes, code not assigning the result of `intern()` appears to work, because calling `intern()` on a string may have the side effect of this instance becoming the canonical instance. This doesn’t happen here, due to the previous assignment, `String s1 = "Testing";`, in other words, the canonical instance for the string `"Testing"` already exists and is referenced by `s1`, which is definitely distinct from the instance referenced by `s2`. So the latter instance can not become the canonical instance and `intern()` must return a different reference, i.e. the same held in `s1`.

Comment: Well, of course, even `new String("Testing")` is sufficient to ensure that the canonical instance and the newly constructed one are distinct. In theory, there could be a runtime that collects the canonical instance before the `intern()` call, if no other references exists, but no real JVM will do that in practice…

Answer (score 2):

Java `String` is immutable, so you must update the `s2` reference.

Change `s2.intern();` to

```
s2 = s2.intern();
```

And it will work the same way.

Comment: Actually, @CKing, the key point to the answer is updating the reference.  The immutability of `String` is a complete red herring - even if `String` were mutable, OP would have had the same issue.  The first snippet fails because OP didn't assign the interned reference back to `s2`.  I feel that Elliott made that particular point more clearly than you did.  But to tell the truth, at the time I upvoted this answer, yours hadn't yet appeared on my screen.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did say in my answer that *you need to reassign any modifications* and elaborated with what I mean by that. I get it, this answer is better I don't deny that. But is it that much better that my answer stays at 0? I generally see this happen a lot here. Most of my accepted answers have fewer votes than the answers that were not accepted on the same quesiton :). Higher rep demands more votes here. That's just my perception. I don't expect anyone to agree. Anyway this is topic better suited for *meta* and is already discussed there so I am off. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Javadoc of `intern()` :

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

Since `String s1 = "Testing";` adds the `String` referenced by `s1` to the `String` pool, `new String("Testing").intern()` returns an instance from the String pool equal to the String created by `new String("Testing")`, which is the same `String` instance referenced by `s1`.

On the other hand, in the first snippet, `s2.intern()` has no effect. The `String` equal to "Testing" is already in the String pool, so the `String` referenced by `s2` is not added to the pool. And you are ignoring the return value of that method, which is the String referenced by `s1`. Therefore `s1` and `s2` refer to different objects.